Why is everyone else different in "Life's Been Good"?
The song Life's been Good by Joe Walsh includes the following:

I go to parties sometimes until four
It's hard to leave when you can't find the door
It's tough to handle this fortune and fame
Everybody's so different, I haven't changed

What does the line "everybody's so different, I haven't changed"? My first thought was that it was a reference to the narrator being in denial about his behavior. However, it occurred to me that it could also refer to people treating him differently because of his "fortune and fame."

The lyrics of the song are intended to be "treated with a light irony", as noted by Record World (June 10, 1978) when the single was released. So, there may be a sense of both things being true. Walsh knows he is living this extravagant life (doing lots of cocaine) and there are people mooching off this, but he is still just a musician.
Walsh explained the song verse by verse during a set at the Troubadour. The general theme being he mixed the song from a bunch of different parts and that lyrics are generally true (e.g., he did tear up hotel rooms, he did own a Maserati).
However, when getting to the final verse he wraps it up pretty quick saying:

A lot of non-musical stuff comes along with success. So that's 'Life's been Good' in nutshell. Everybody thinks I knew what I was doing. I didn't have a clue. It's all in different keys. It's all in bits and pieces.

A lot was going on in Joe's life around that time, he lost his three-year-old daughter in a car crash in 1974 and was going through a divorce by 1978. It isn't hard to imagine a man thinking that world and people around him are changing in a way he not does like, but also is not in a frame of mind to fully take accountability for his own role in the outcome.
